# variadic template only using type parameter

Tags: c++

I would like to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class a {

public:
    a() : i(2) {}

    template <typename ...ts>
    void exec() {
        f<ts...>();
        std::cout << "a::()" << std::endl;
    }

    int i;
private:

    template <typename t>
    void f() {
        i += t::i;
    }

    template <typename t, typename ...ts>
    void f() {
        f<t>();
        f<t, ts...>();
    }
};

struct b {
    static const int i = -9;
};

struct c {
    static const int i = 4;
};


int main()
{
    a _a;

    _a.exec<b,c>();

    std::cout << _a.i << std::endl;
}
```

The idea is to get the same information from a group of classes, without the need of an object of each class.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)? Or maybe make `exec` have `template <int ...ts>` template arguments?

Comment: `f<t, ts...>();` would do infinite recursive call, you probably mean `f<ts...>();`

Comment: Jarod42, you are right. I posted the code without this correction. But, even them, it does not compile, reporting ambiguous call from two calls to the same 'f'.

Comment: Variant of your code, using tag parameter to select correct overload [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db5395d77807c8d1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case Your compiler does not support C++17:

```
template <typename ...ts>
void f() {
    for ( const auto &j : { ts::i... } )
        i += j;
}
```

Comment: Which looks even better than folding expression IMO.

Comment: @Jarod42 It is shorter, not more readable. Can someone explain to me how this works, btw?

Comment: @NO_NAME Long story short - it creates an initializer list from `i`s from all the classes and iterates over them. It works ONLY because the `i`s are all the same type

Comment: I retract what I said. It only seem shorter because you didn't write code of the class. Although now, as I understand this, it strikes me that this loop is an exact equivalent to the @Jarod42 's code. C++17 just provides a shorter way (maybe also more flexible) to write such loops.

Answer (score 3):

In C++17, your class would simply be

```
class a {

public:
    a() : i(2) {}

    template <typename ...ts>
    void exec() {
        ((i += ts::i), ...); // Folding expression // C++17
        std::cout << "a::()" << std::endl;
    }

    int i;
};
```

Possible in C++11 too, but more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons why your code is not compiling:

1. Syntax of specializing templates is a little different.
2. You need to put the most general case first.
3. You can't partially specialize functions, only classes.
4. Partial specialization is not allowed within classes, only in namespaces.

Here is an example for C++11.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename t, typename ...ts>
class a {
public:
    static constexpr int x = t::i + a<ts...>::x;
};

template<typename t>
class a<t> {
public:
    static constexpr int x = 2 + t::i;
};

struct b {
    static constexpr int i = -9;
};

struct c {
    static constexpr int i = 4;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int result = a<b,c>::x;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Remember that templates are calculated during compilation so, for optimization sake, it is a good idea to write them in a way that allows them to be `constexpr`.

Comment: *"Syntax of specializing templates is a little different"*: It is actually overloads and not specialization.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think that overloading applies only if functions have different parameters.